# compactness of sequence of harmonic functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Let $ \Omega$ denote a smooth bounded domain in $ R^N$ and let $u_m \in C^\infty( \overline{\Omega})$ harmonic functions.    We also suppose $ u_m$ is bounded in $L^2(\Omega)$ (uniformly in $m$).

Question. Suppose $N=2$.  Can we find a subsequence which converges in $L^2(\Omega).$

Note for $N \ge 4$ we could take $u_m(x)= \frac{t_m}{|x-x^m|^{N-2}}$ where $x^m$ is such that $dist(x_m ,\Omega)=\delta_m$  and we could then take $t_m$ related to $\delta_m$ such that $\| u_m\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=1$ and such that $u_m \rightarrow 0$ a.e. in $\Omega$;  and hence we cannot find a subsequence that converges in $L^2$.

thanks

Comment: $x / (x^2 + y^2)$ is harmonic outside of the origin and is not square integrable in the unit disc.

Comment: Consider $\sqrt n \Re(z^n)$ in the unit disk